# Reverse an encryption algorithem in APK .so file

Tags: disassembly, android, c, arm

I try to reverse a cipher algorithm (I guess Tiny Encryption Algorithm (TEA)) in an android application. But I have a serious problem in initializing arguments. **How I can understand that I have selected the input arguments correctly?(Especially when they are pointer)**
This algorithm get 4 bytes from user(typed in a textbox)and other 4 bytes from an external hardware and mix up this 8 bytes and export 4 bytes for us.
So, I have shown this algorithm in below:

```
                EXPORT Mycipher
Mycipher                                
                                        

var_20          = -0x20
var_1C          = -0x1C

                PUSH    {R0-R2,R4-R7,LR}
                MOVS    R3, #0
                STR     R0, [SP,#0x20+var_20]
                LDR     R4, [R1]
                LDR     R0, [R1,#4]
                MOVS    R5, R3
                MOVS    R6, #3
                MOV     R12, R1
                B       loc_DADC
; ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

loc_DAA6                                ; CODE XREF: Mycipher+4C
                MOVS    R1, R3
                ANDS    R1, R6
                LSLS    R1, R1, #2
                LDR     R1, [R1,R2]
                LSLS    R7, R0, #4
                ADDS    R5, #1
                ADDS    R1, R3, R1
                STR     R1, [SP,#0x20+var_1C]
                LSRS    R1, R0, #5
                EORS    R7, R1
                LDR     R1, [SP,#0x20+var_1C]
                ADDS    R7, R7, R0
                EORS    R7, R1
                LDR     R1, =0x9E3779B9
                ADDS    R4, R4, R7
                LSRS    R7, R4, #5
                ADDS    R3, R3, R1
                LSLS    R1, R4, #4
                EORS    R7, R1
                LSRS    R1, R3, #0xB
                ANDS    R1, R6
                LSLS    R1, R1, #2
                LDR     R1, [R1,R2]
                ADDS    R7, R7, R4
                ADDS    R1, R3, R1
                EORS    R1, R7
                ADDS    R0, R0, R1

loc_DADC                                ; CODE XREF: Mycipher+10
                LDR     R1, [SP,#0x20+var_20]
                CMP     R5, R1
                BNE     loc_DAA6
                MOV     R1, R12
                STR     R4, [R1]
                STR     R0, [R1,#4]
                POP     {R0-R2,R4-R7,PC}
; End of function Mycipher
```

Then I reverse this algorithm to C code :

```
void Mycipher (uint32_t* v, const uint32_t* k ) {
    uint32_t v0=v[0] ,v1=v[1], sum=0, i;
for (i=0; i<2; i++) {
    v0 += ((v1 << 4u ^ v1 >> 5u) + v1) ^ (uint32_t)(sum + *(uint32_t *)(((sum & 3u) * 4u) + k));
    sum = sum + 0x9e3779b9;
    v1 += (sum + *(uint32_t *)((sum >> 0xb & 3u) * 4u + k) ^ (v0 >> 5u ^ v0 * 0x10) + v0);
}
v[0]=v0; v[1]=v1;
}
```

And you can see the piece of code that exactly there is in before of function invoke:

```
STR     R3, [SP,#0x258+var_248]
MOVS    R0, #2
MVNS    R3, R3
ADD     R1, SP, #0x258+var_248
ADD     R2, SP, #0x258+var_240
STR     R3, [SP,#0x258+var_244]
BL      Mycipher
```

But I don't know **how I can determine the input arguments type?** For example, I put the second argument as `const` because the cLion suggest me(Not for my knowledge). Or, In this case **which line of code that shown above I must consider for input arguments?** Now, I think my conversion have some problems(I'm suspicious to my codes) and I like to know how I can fix these problems.
Sorry for eating your time.
Thanks

Comment: You need to inspect those values at run-time when the function is originally called, so you can make sense of the arguments meaning.

Comment: I have to analyze this app statically. I guess you mean, I to-dos in debug mode. Otherwise, how I can inspect those in run time?

Comment: What forces you to debug it statically? You can normally run gdb server on your android device and then debug the .so from your PC instruction by instruction. Eventually you can hook the `Mycipher` using tools like Frida and then inspect it's parameters.

Comment: I tried to do it but I couldn't. So I decided analyzing this statically.